# Filepond set plugin properties

Tags: filepond

Many Filepond plugins have properties available to modify their behaviour e.g. https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/image-validate-size/#properties.

How do I change them? The Filepond documentation shows how to register a plugin, but not how to customise the properties. I have tried to set them directly on the object:

```js
FilePondPluginImageValidateSize.imageValidateSizeLabelExpectedMinSize = 'Foo';
```

and looked for a `setProperties`/`setOptions` method, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass them to the FilePond constructor, for example:

```
const myInstance = FilePond.create({
  maxFileSize: '5MB'
});
```