# In svelte-filepond, how to pass parameters to plugins?

Tags: svelte, filepond

In svelte-filepond, how to pass parameters to plugins? There is only one anser on filepond itself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575326/filepond-set-plugin-properties), but nothing mentioned in the svelte-filepond docs (not in filepond docs itself, which is strange).

Comment: It's not super explicit, but the [FilePond Svelte docs](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/frameworks/svelte/) do address this and point to https://github.com/pqina/svelte-filepond/blob/master/example/src/App.svelte as an example.

Comment: In the example file there is no property set on any plugin, that's the problem (would send a PR with a better example(. It is mentioned in docs, however. Actually, I just looked at the source first.

Answer (score 2):

OK, it is kind of easy: all the properties passed to the  component are used as plugins' properties, for example:

```
<Pond imageValidateSizeMaxWidth={100} .../>
```

Will set `imageValidateSizeMaxWidth` property of the [FilePondPluginImageValidateSize](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/image-validate-size/) plugin.